# Which editor is this print from?

Tags: printing, text-editors

I received a [print like this](http://217.77.37.118/095027.pdf) a few days ago, and I just loved the way the editor prints source code. If anyone knows which editor this is, please give me an answer

Comment: question about a text editor, voting to move to superuser

Comment: So you have no idea

Answer (score 3):

I am quite sure it is output from [`a2ps`](http://www.gnu.org/software/a2ps/), which is simply a converter from plain text files to postscript. Some people use it as a standard filter applied automatically when printing plain text on printers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with printing from editors, but this might be LaTeX with the `listings` package. For example, this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstset{
  language=python,
  numbers=left,
  frame=single,
  title=exemplum
}

\begin{lstlisting}
import sys
import random

for x in range(10000):
    result = 126
    ...

\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

yields
[image]

I guess it can be tweaked to show a border around it and have the line numbers within the border. Don't know how to do it though.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* its [jedit](http://jedit.org).

EDIT: its not from jedit. But has appearantly about the same features wrt print formatting